# Best way to get length of numpy unicode string dtype

Tags: python, string, numpy

I am trying to determine the maximum element length of a numpy unicode array. For example, if I have:

```
# (dtypes added for clarity)
a = np.array(['a'], dtype='U5')
print(get_dtype_length(a))
```

I'd like it to print `5`.

I can do something like:

```
def get_dtype_length(a):
  dtype = a.dtype
  dtype_string = dtype.descr[0][1]  # == '<U5'
  length = int(dtype_string[2:])
  return length
```

But that seems like a roundabout way of inferring something that must be available somewhere. Is there an attribute or numpy function that I haven't found to do this directly?

**Clarification based on comments:**

I am specifically looking for the maximum allowable length of any element in the array, not the length of any specific element (eg, not `len(a[0]) == 1`.  The motivation behind this is that if I try to update a by something like `a[0] = 'string_longer_than_dtype_of_a'` I don't want the element to truncate to `stri`.

In numpy version 1.19 I believe `np.can_cast(newVal.dtype, a.dtype, casting='safe')` would be a valid test for my use case (as in 1.19 safe will also test if casting results in truncation), but it still doesn't actually solve the question of testing character size.

Comment: @MadPhysicist but in this case the item size is not equal to 4, which is the answer OP is looking for

Comment: @myrtlecat. Totally misread the question. Apologies.

Comment: Then again, maybe the answer is `a.dtype.itemsize / 4`? Does numpy always use 4 bytes per code point to store unicode?

Comment: @myrtlecat. Probably just `a.dtype.base.itemsize`

Comment: Wow. This is really non-trivial. So far, `a.dtype.itemsize / alen([0])`, but that's unreliable.

Comment: This is a strange example. Could you please rewrite it with `aaa` instead of `aaaa`? The problem is that both the string length and the character size are 4. Which one do you want? Because ATM, the 4 you are returning is *not* the string length, but rather the character size.

Comment: Refactored example to be clear the goal is extracting character size, not the string length

Comment: @hpaulj Could you take a look at this and comment? I feel that my solution is completely inadequate.

Comment: @divakar Could you take a look at this and comment? I feel that my solution is completely inadequate.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Could you take a look at this and comment? I feel that my solution is completely inadequate.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Maybe I'm missing something, but what's wrong with `Usize = np.dtype("U1").itemsize`, `a.itemsize // Usize`?

Comment: @PaulPanzer. You missed nothing. This whole time OP and I have been working under the assumption that the 4 in U4 is the byte size of a character, not the buffer size. Thanks for clearing that up. Do you mind if I absorb that into my answer?

Comment: @Andrew. I've rewritten my answer

Comment: @myrtlecat. You were right

Comment: I think I accidentally did a few things that made this more confusing too.  I used the term "character size" when really it should have been something more like maximum string length, and happened to use U4 which by chance I picked a number that is the same as U1's itemsize.  Editing the post to remove these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `4` in `U4` is the length of the string for each element, not the size of the character:

> The first character specifies the kind of data and the remaining characters specify the number of bytes per item, except for Unicode, where it is interpreted as the number of characters.

From [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types).

The size of a single Unicode character can be a constant in your program:

```
 sizeof_numpy_unicode_char = np.dtype('U1').itemsize
```

You can then divide the total number of bytes per element by this constant to get buffer sizes, using either [`dtype.itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.itemsize.html), or the shortcut [`ndarray.itemsize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.itemsize.html):

```
def get_length(a):
    return a.itemsize // sizeof_numpy_unicode_char
```

But the size of characters is indeed fixed (usually at 4 bytes).

Comment: Still feels like there should be a more direct way, but I like this more than interpreting the string as an integer.  I have no sense of when `np.dtype('U1').itemsize` might change, but still feels better.

Comment: @Andrew. If you make the constant in your module, `np.dtype('U1').itemsize` will not change within your script. You can always select this answer if it works well.

Comment: Yeah I guess if it changed it would be across system or numpy version or something?  In any case, not within a running script

Comment: Thanks, this works fine ... don't use the following as I did before `sizeof_numpy_unicode_char = np.unicode_('x').itemsize` which gives 2 on Win32 and 4 on Linux, whereas `np.dtype('U1').itemsize` is self-referencing and gives 4 on Win32 and Linux